# Why is my parquet partitioned data slower than non-partitioned one?

Tags: apache-spark, parquet

My understanding is: If I partition my data on a column I will query by it should be faster. However, when I tried it, it seem to be slower instead why?

I have a users dataframe which I tried partitioning my `yearmonth` and not.

So I have 1 dataset partitioned by `creation_yearmonth`.

```
questionsCleanedDf.repartition("creation_yearmonth") \
    .write.partitionBy('creation_yearmonth') \
    .parquet('wasb://.../parquet/questions.parquet')
```

I have another not partitioned

```
questionsCleanedDf \
    .write \
    .parquet('wasb://.../parquet/questions_nopartition.parquet')
```

Then I tried creating a dataframe from these 2 parquet files and running the same query

```
questionsDf = spark.read.parquet('wasb://.../parquet/questions.parquet')
```

and

```
questionsDf = spark.read.parquet('wasb://.../parquet/questions_nopartition.parquet')
```

The query

```
spark.sql("""
    SELECT * FROM questions
    WHERE creation_yearmonth = 201606
""")
```

It seem like the no partition one is consistently faster or have similar times (~2 - 3s) while partitioned one is slighly slower (~3 - 4s).

I tried to do an explain:

For the partitioned dataset:

```
== Physical Plan ==
*FileScan parquet [id#6404,title#6405,tags#6406,owner_user_id#6407,accepted_answer_id#6408,view_count#6409,answer_count#6410,comment_count#6411,creation_date#6412,favorite_count#6413,creation_yearmonth#6414] Batched: false, Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[wasb://data@cs4225.blob.core.windows.net/parquet/questions.parquet], PartitionCount: 1, PartitionFilters: [isnotnull(creation_yearmonth#6414), (creation_yearmonth#6414 = 201606)], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<id:int,title:string,tags:array<string>,owner_user_id:int,accepted_answer_id:int,view_count...
```

**`PartitionCount: 1`** I should since in this case, it can just go directly to the parition it should be faster?

For the non-paritioned one:

```
== Physical Plan ==
*Project [id#6440, title#6441, tags#6442, owner_user_id#6443, accepted_answer_id#6444, view_count#6445, answer_count#6446, comment_count#6447, creation_date#6448, favorite_count#6449, creation_yearmonth#6450]
+- *Filter (isnotnull(creation_yearmonth#6450) && (creation_yearmonth#6450 = 201606))
   +- *FileScan parquet [id#6440,title#6441,tags#6442,owner_user_id#6443,accepted_answer_id#6444,view_count#6445,answer_count#6446,comment_count#6447,creation_date#6448,favorite_count#6449,creation_yearmonth#6450] Batched: false, Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[wasb://data@cs4225.blob.core.windows.net/parquet/questions_nopartition.parquet], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(creation_yearmonth), EqualTo(creation_yearmonth,201606)], ReadSchema: struct<id:int,title:string,tags:array<string>,owner_user_id:int,accepted_answer_id:int,view_count...
```

---

Also very surprising. At first the dataset has dates as strings, so I need to do a query like:

```
spark.sql("""
    SELECT * FROM questions
    WHERE CAST(creation_date AS date) BETWEEN '2017-06-01' AND '2017-07-01'
""").show(20, False)
```

I expected this to be even slower but it turns out, it performs the best ~1-2s. Why is that? I thought in this case, it needs to cast each row?

The explain output here:

```
== Physical Plan ==
*Project [id#6521, title#6522, tags#6523, owner_user_id#6524, accepted_answer_id#6525, view_count#6526, answer_count#6527, comment_count#6528, creation_date#6529, favorite_count#6530]
+- *Filter ((isnotnull(creation_date#6529) && (cast(cast(creation_date#6529 as date) as string) >= 2017-06-01)) && (cast(cast(creation_date#6529 as date) as string) <= 2017-07-01))
   +- *FileScan parquet [id#6521,title#6522,tags#6523,owner_user_id#6524,accepted_answer_id#6525,view_count#6526,answer_count#6527,comment_count#6528,creation_date#6529,favorite_count#6530] Batched: false, Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[wasb://data@cs4225.blob.core.windows.net/filtered/questions.parquet], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(creation_date)], ReadSchema: struct<id:string,title:string,tags:array<string>,owner_user_id:string,accepted_answer_id:string,v...
```

Comment: You don't show how you benchmark this code so it is not even clear what these values represent. But just looking at the range and difference combined with object storage I'd guess that majority of that time is spend on scanning "file system" and reading metadata and data is not large enough for meaningful benchmarking.

Comment: @user6910411 I am using HDInsight/Jupyter Notebook where I cannot seem to use the `%time` function... So I roughly time it manually. You maybe right regarding file size ... each parquet file is ~10-60MB. Even without proper benchmarking it somehow seem to give consistent but unexpected performance

Comment: Total dataset size in parquet is only 900MB if that matters

Comment: 900 is way to low for useful benchmarking (8 cores or so is enough to fully cover all data). Even if you measure time manually it would nice to know what you measure  (`show` is not useful here).

Comment: What's the number of partitions in both cases? (questionsDf.rdd.getNumPartitions()).

Comment: @user6910411 I am measuring the time taken to run `show()` but why is that not useful? I thought I am running the time taken to run this query.

Comment: First of foremost because in general it will evaluate only as much data as possible. There are more subtle issues here (result latency is not the best measure of performance in distributed system, also you're likely to measure things which are not really related to the task), but this alone is a deal breaker.

Comment: There are some other issues with your methodology - notebook measurements are in general not independent, external object store is possible confounder, and so on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overpartitioning can actually reduce performance:

> If a column has only a few rows matching each value, the number of
>   directories to process can become a limiting factor, and the data file
>   in each directory could be too small to take advantage of the Hadoop
>   mechanism for transmitting data in multi-megabyte blocks.

This excerpt was taken from the documentation of a different Hadoop component, [Impala](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/cdh/5-0-x/Impala/Installing-and-Using-Impala/ciiu_partitioning.html), but the presented argument should be valid to all components of the Hadoop stack.

I think that regardless of the partitioning scheme used, the advantages of partitioning will not be apparent until the table grows way beyond 900 MB-s.